# Send all of a dropdown in Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to send a full array of custom field to a mail (dynamicaly populate) with contact Form 7 to work it here before sending :

```php
// define the wpcf7_posted_data callback
function action_wpcf7_posted_data($array)
{
    $a = get_field('date')
    //WORK HERE

    $array['Nom & Prénom'] = $array['name'];
    unset($array['name']);

    $array['E-mail'] = $array['email'];
    unset($array['email']);

    $array['Téléphone'] = $array['tel'];
    unset($array['tel']);

    $array['Profession'] = $array['job'];
    unset($array['job']);

    $array['Session'] = $array['upcoming-gigs'];
    unset($array['upcoming-gigs']);

    unset($array['privacy']);

    return $array;
}

add_filter('wpcf7_posted_data', 'action_wpcf7_posted_data', 10, 1);
```

Because it's before sending a mail I can't call anything to compare before sending.

So I want to send all the data in a hidden input next to compare it.

This the two input in contact Form 7 :

```php
      [select upcoming-gigs data:gigs id:date] [hidden select upcoming-gigs2 data:gigs2]
```

My goal here is to send all the data of the hidden select.

I don't find a way to send all input in the mail.

Is it possible ? There is a better way ?

Thx

EDIT :

My question mark2 :

The goal is to send a mail with the date of the session and the id of it.

I use ACF and I have :

[image]

And after a dynamic dropdown, it's look like this for the user :

[image]

The problem is I don't have the id of the session, only the date.

To know the id I need to compar to the array of all the custom field, I can't import it during `wpcf7_posted_data`.

I think if I send all the data of the array in a hidden field, I could remake the array and find the id of the session my user choose.

I hope I'm clearer.

(I can't make a request in php during `wpcf7_posted_data`. Can I make an ajax request ?)

EDIT2 :
This my hidden select with session and text
[image]

This is the html of contact form 7 the rest is div for CSS
`[select upcoming-date data:date id:date] [hidden select upcoming-date2 data:date2]`

EDIT3 :
Okay get it.

The custom fields I use to make the dropdown are in two part id and text. I have the text part I need the id.

If I send every text and id in the mail I can compare to the answer of the user et add to the mail the right id.

Here the generated html : http://www.sharemycode.fr/5ax

EDIT 4 :
That where I write the id and text of the dropdown :

[image]

That where I create the select :

```php
add_filter('wpcf7_form_tag_data_option', function ($n, $options, $args) {
    $ses = (array)get_field('date_new');
    $sesCount = count($ses);
    $gigs = [];
    $gigs2 = [];

    if (in_array('gigs', $options)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $sesCount; $i++) {
            if ($ses[$i]['date_start'] > date('d-m-Y', time())) {
                $a = "A réaliser entre le " . $ses[$i]['date_start'] . " et le " . $ses[$i]['date_end'] ." | bla";
                array_push($gigs, $a);
            }
        }
        return $gigs;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a hidden select?  What would the value be?  Can you illustrate your example with an actual sample of the form data, and what you hope to send to the email?

Comment: I Have two custom field session_number and session_text. The user choose the session_text in a dropdown and I want to had before the mail is sending the depending session_number.

I can't make any request because of the hook so I want to send all the value of the session_number and session_text to compare it and add to a mail the right session_number

Comment: Ok, can you please add additional info to your question to illustrate this.  Add the select, and the possible result, and how will it determine what to send to whom?  You can definitely compare values using `wpcf7_before_send_mail` it's still unclear from your question however, what that is.

Comment: I use [ACF](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to create custom fields but I can call a request during ```wpcf7_before_send_mail``` (like I edit in the question line 4). The array of $a is empty. So I can't have data to compare to the choice of my user

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is still too vague to help you. What is the purpose of a hidden `select` field anyway?  You can definitely use ajax and hidden form fields to evaluate and pass data on user action, but your question doesn't give enough real information to try and replicate this on my own.

Comment: @howard-e I edit it ;)

Comment: I'm unclear still about the purpose of a hidden select.  Why use a select.  Can this just be a hidden text field with an array of data returned?

Comment: The purpose is to send all the data, sending an array in a text field should work too. How do you do that ?

Comment: So are you already passing the id and date to a `<select>` in the form?  So you just need to evaluate the selected option after it's submitted?

Comment: YES !!! :D I need the id of the session whitch my user select !

Comment: Can you share in the question the values of the select options? Include a snippet of the generated html please.

Comment: Update :) @HowardE

Comment: So, you are using `[select upcoming-gigs data:gigs id:date]` and from this, you want the option value, but since 'gigs' is dynamically generated, you can't use the `|` for the value.  So you want to get the value - which is the post_id to show?  You are not showing what the generated form field looks like... like this for example: https://imgur.com/IW4Zm8p

Comment: Update :D @HowardE

Comment: So what it sounds like you want is   [select upcoming-gigs data:gigs id:date]  to have the `<option value="123">A réaliser du 19-06-2021 au 24-06-2021</option>` and to do this, I would recommend creating your own form tag [gigs] instead of using [select] - so how are you getting the data for `gigs` tag?  is there a wp_query for this? Once you explain this part... I can help you craft a form tag.

Comment: Yeah it's could be perfect.Update @HowardE

Comment: If you find my answer helpful and correct then please make it marked, so it will be helpful to other people also.

Comment: @AjayKatariya, it's help but I can't use because I dynamicaly generates the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a custom form tag for the select.  The following code will create a custom form tag called `[gigs]` which would be used like this:

`[gigs upcoming-gigs]`

I've also included ability to add the * and make it required.

My assumptions are how you're actually getting the ACF fields, which I can't actually do, since I don't have them, and you haven't completely shared how it's stored.  You would add this to your functions.php.

```php
add_action('wpcf7_init', function (){
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( array('gigs', 'gigs*'), 'dd_cf7_upcoming_gigs' , array('name-attr' => true) );
});
function dd_cf7_upcoming_gigs($tag) {

    if ( empty( $tag->name ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    $validation_error = wpcf7_get_validation_error( $tag->name );

    $class = wpcf7_form_controls_class( $tag->type );


    if ( $validation_error ) {
        $class .= ' wpcf7-not-valid';
    }

    $atts = array();

    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
    $atts['id'] = $tag->get_id_option();
    $atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option( 'tabindex', 'signed_int', true );

    if ( $tag->is_required() ) {
        $atts['aria-required'] = 'true';
    }

    if ( $validation_error ) {
        $atts['aria-invalid'] = 'true';
        $atts['aria-describedby'] = wpcf7_get_validation_error_reference(
            $tag->name
        );
    } else {
        $atts['aria-invalid'] = 'false';
    }
    // Make first option unselected and please choose
    $html = '<option value="">- - '. __('Please Choose', 'text-domain'). ' - -</option>';

    // This part you may have to update with your custom fields
    $ses = (array)get_field('date_new');
    $sesCount = count($ses);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $sesCount; $i++) {
        if ($ses[$i]['date_start'] > date('d-m-Y', time())) {
            $a = "A réaliser entre le " . $ses[$i]['date_start'] . " et le " . $ses[$i]['date_end'];
            // if session ID is in fact $ses[$i]['session']
            $html .= sprintf( '<option %1$s>%2$s</option>',
                $ses[$i]['session'], $a );
        }
    }
    
    foreach ($gigs as $key => $value){
        $html .= sprintf( '<option %1$s>%2$s</option>',
            $key, $value );
    }

    $atts['name'] = $tag->name;

    $atts = wpcf7_format_atts( $atts );

    $html = sprintf(
        '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %1$s"><select %2$s>%3$s</select>%4$s</span>',
        sanitize_html_class( $tag->name ), $atts, $html, $validation_error
    );

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_gigs', 'dd_validate_gigs_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_gigs*', 'dd_validate_gigs_filter', 10, 2 );

function dd_validate_gigs_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    $name = $tag->name;

    $has_value = isset( $_POST[$name] ) && '' !== $_POST[$name];

    if ( $has_value and $tag->has_option( 'multiple' ) ) {
        $vals = array_filter( (array) $_POST[$name], function( $val ) {
            return '' !== $val;
        } );

        $has_value = ! empty( $vals );
    }

    if ( $tag->is_required() and ! $has_value ) {
        $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is supported by Contact Form 7 natively, it's just not very obvious on how to make it happen.

Here's a documentation page explaining the functionality: http://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Basically all you have to do is put the values like so:

Visible Value|actual-form-value

What comes before the pipe "|" character will be shown in the form, and what comes after will be the actual value filled in for the form.

EDIT kanarpp :
I add my code here to separate the answer of HowardE.

This is how I dynamicaly create my select :

```php
   add_filter('wpcf7_form_tag_data_option', function ($n, $options, $args) {
    $ses = (array)get_field('date');
    $sesCount = count($ses);
    $date= [];

    if (in_array('date', $options)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $sesCount; $i++) {
            if ($ses[$i]['date_start'] > date('d-m-Y', time())) {
                $a = "A réaliser entre le " . $ses[$i]['date_start'] . " et le " . $ses[$i]['date_end'] ." | bla";
                array_push($date, $a);
            }
        }
        return $date;
    }
```

It's not working, I use Smart Grid-Layout Design for Contact Form 7 to create dynmicaly my select

Comment: This answer would be correct if the values were actually set without using the `data` method. So in this case... This is the wrong answer.